# How to show 80-character column line in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, wrap

I am used to use Texmaker, and now wondering how to set up Texmaker so that it could:

(1) show 80-character column line;

(2) do hard word wrap at 80-character column line, meaning that it automatically breaks to a new line when reaching 80 characters.

Comment: See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1259&q=limit&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary) in the Texmaker issue tracker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Alternative solution (another editor)**

If you wish you can try another editor. *[TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/)* is very good and powerful and it is based on TeXmaker. So you will not change so much what you know.

TeXstudio allows you to determine the number of characters for wrapping lines and also how to wrap.

See the Configure for Advanced Editor options (note the *Show Advanced Options* checked on the left bottom corner):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That looks like a good alternative.

Comment: This is denied by its author at the bottom of the page here: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html Note : This program is the "authentic" Texmaker editor and there is strictly no relationship between this original program developed since 2003 and another latex editor, not compatible with Texmaker, which pretends to be based on Texmaker to trick users.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [release notes](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) TexMaker (> Version 4.4) is using a script to hardwrap your code. This script needs to be triggered manually as shown below (Menu: User -> Run Script, unfortnately I have a German system only).

[image: Menu entry for script]

However, TexMaker does not have any functionality to do this automatically or to show the desired 80-char-line as stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1259).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a last ditch method but might work for the ease of typing:
Go to Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Editor tab

[image]

and check the option Word Wrap. This will wrap the typed text at the border between the typing area and the pdf display. Now you can measure the 80 character length by typing in 80 characters and set the border accordingly. This should wrap the text for the current session, but not if you copy paste it anywhere else.