# Word-wrap in TeXmaker editor (how to NOT have a whole paragraph as one line)

Tags: texmaker, wrap

I am new to LaTeX and am using TeXmaker on Windows 7.
Now, I would like to know how to wrap text in this software. Because now I have written a whole paragraph, which, however, has only one line number.
(See the example - the whole paragraph is line 1)
[image]

I tried the solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248859/125700), I went to User -> Run script -> hardwordwrap_selection_80col - but it (as name suggests) only works on a selection.

**Is there any way to make it work for the whole document?**

Comment: I would have a look at text editors like Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks @Dr. Manuel Kuehner, I have Notepad ++, but it does not have the option to compile the document and turn it as pdf, neither it provides the document structure. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Editor tab, like this:

[image]

Comment: ... and the changes he needs to make in that menu are...

Comment: Funny. The Word Wrap option is checked in my menu. So why isn't it happening? Do I need to set the number of characters after which it wraps manually somewhere? (One would expect the 80 characters would be default. But maybe not.) Where?

Comment: I've just checked it adapts to the actual width of the edit window. I don't understand. What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7. As you can see in the printscreen, the actual text does adapt to the width of the window, but the line count does not.

Comment: I see. That is normal, and all editors do the same (I don't use TeXmaker usually). The editor counts a new line only if there is a hard return, not for soft returns. Otherwise, if you count the number of lines of a document, it would depend on the window size or the screen size. Imagine what a mess if you share the document with someone else: how would you refer to line no xxx?